# Function being called faster

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I hava made a **flappy bird** game and there are 2 frames. frame `1` is for playing while `2` is for death. I put a `trace` call on a function to see how many times is it called due to a problem. I found out that the more i die , the speedy my function call gets and the `gravity` is increased more times, so, my character `flappy` falls faster each time it dies.Please help. Here's the code:

```
var calls = 0;
flappy.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_gravity);
function fl_gravity(event: Event): void {
    calls++;
    if (dead) {
        if (flappy.hitTestObject(ground)) {
            gravity = 0;
        } else {
            gravity += 0.5;
        }
        upPressed = false;
    } else {
        flappy.x += 2.5;
    }
    flappy.y += gravity;
    gravity += 0.5;
    trace(calls);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably happens because when you die and get back to frame 1 (where this code probably is) you add another enterframe listener so now your function is executed twice per frame (one time for each event listener). Make sure you add your event listener only once:

```
var initialized:Boolean;

if(!initialized)
{
    initialized = true;
    flappy.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_gravity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're increasing the bird's gravity not only if it isn't dead but if it is. It lies outside of the conditional. Remove the line that increases your gravity outside of the conditional (line 16 in that excerpt)